# Excel formula to R script; How to make column 3 the sum of column 1 and the locked first value of column 2

Tags: r, excel, dplyr, converters

Value of column 3 is the sum of column 1 and the locked (or set) first value of column 2. In addition, how to let the new column take on the first value of each group_by() from the reference column.

Hej!

I am working with ages, and have the following code so far:

```
DataFrame <- DataFrame %>%
  mutate(AGE2=0) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(AGE2=as.numeric(difftime(SDATE, SDATE[1], units = "days"))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(AGE3= AGE2/365.25,
         AGE4=0) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(AGE4 = ...)
```

The first question is how to obtain the first value per group of AGE in AGE4.
The second question is how to get AGE4 to add AGE3 upon its first value per group in AGE4, as simplified below:

In essence, I want to know how to write the Excel formula of: `C2 = B$1 + A2` in R code (with packages dplyr or tidyverse, most likely with mutate). It should be simple, yet I have no clue how to write it.

Basically the dataset should look like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 6 | 6 |
| 2 | 7 | 8 |
| 5 | 6 | 11 |

In which A would be AGE2, B would be AGE and C would be AGE4 (AGE4 would be AGE + AGE3). AGE4 is the ultimate desired AGE to be used.

AGE has mistakes in the original ages in it, making it NOT possible to add two columns to each other to get the answer.

Comment: Try if the `first(B)` function will work

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```r
library(dplyr) 

df |>
  group_by(ID) |>
  mutate(AGE4 = first(AGE) + AGE2)
```

`first(AGE)` will give the first value of age for each group.